# I have an array but only the first element is being outputted

Tags: java

I am writing a program that keeps track of memory. The max memory is 3000 and once that number is reached, the process entered will be thrown into a waiting Q (separate box). My problem is that I have an array of up to 7 elements, but when I enter the first element, it outputs 7 times. I'm not sure what else I need to change to have 7 different elements output.

```
int processes[]= new int [7];

String s1 = IDbox.getText();
String s2 = IDsize.getText();
int x;
for (x=0;x<processes.length;x++)
{                   
    if (totalmem <= 3000)
    {
        memory.append(s1 + "     " + s2);
        memory.append("\n");

        totalmem = totalmem + idsize;       
    }
    else
    {
        memory.setText("Memory is already full");
        //throw into waiting queue
        waitingQ.append(s1 + "     " + s2);
        waitingQ.append( "\n");
    }       
}//end for
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that the code doesn't make sense (you never use x nor processes), your statement is wrong, You don't have an array of up to 7 elements, you have an array of exactly 7 elements, always, for the array's entire lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Your integer array's size is 7, and your `int[]` array declaration is wrong.

Do this:

```
int memory = 3000;
int[] processes = new int[memory];
```

I would also declare `int x = 0` within the for-loop. For scope issues.